# BizTalk: multiple request response subscriptions

Tags: wcf, biztalk

We have a stored procedure that logs status to our database. For an existing application the users decided they wanted to write the status to a different server.

- We duplicated the table and stored procedure on the new server
- I created a new wcf-custom send port and configured it to use the new database.
- I changed the orchestration binding to use the new send port.

Now I get the following error:

```
The message found multiple request response subscriptions. A message can only be routed to a single request response subscription.
```

I believe that though the orchestration binding specifies which port to use BizTalk is also finding the old send port definition as well.

How does the orchestration binding work? Any ideas why it's confused?

(The original send port is used by other applications, so I can't remove or edit it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind an Orchestration to a port any message for that port the Orchestration publishes will have a Context Property of SPTransportID set to the GUID of the port. When you add a filter to a port it adds it as an OR. You can see this by going to New Query, Search For Subscriptions and finding the port in question. For example you will see a subscription like this

```
http: //schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties.SPTransportID == {E1293B10-2763-4600-B795-A0C4B4D5E6EC} 
   Or 
http: //schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties.ReceivePortName == ExamplePort
```

So to resolve this issue will need to either update the filter of the old port so that it excludes the messages from the Orchestration you are re-pointing.  Or if the other if the other applications Orchestrations are bound to the old port, you can just remove the filter and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I'll test it shortly.

Comment: Wow. Did not expect that behavior. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It seems that either the old port is still enlisted (it might just be [stopped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee253550%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)), or possibly you need to restart your `BizTalk` hosts.

Comment: The old port is still required for other BizTalk applications. I'll try restarting the hosts though. Good idea

Comment: This could be a problem - as per the error, a `request response` message can't have multiple port subscriptions, as otherwise the triggering orch's can potentially get more than one reply, possibly conflicting. Can you make the subscriptions on the 2 ports mutually exclusive, e.g. with context property filters?

Comment: I agree. So why do two different ports, one of which is not bound to this orchestration, count as possible subscribers? What criteria does it use to decide which port is used? It's got to be something besides the binding.

Comment: You possibly have used direct binding on at least one of them, with the filter based only on `message type`?

Comment: It does have a filter criteria on message type. It's not a messagebox direct bound port. I've restarted host instances and we're going to rerun the job. I'm wondering if it created the new send port but since I didn't bounce the instances it still holds a reference to the other one too.

Comment: Restarting host instances did not fix the issue :(

Comment: It's not really obvious what to do to fix the issue so I'm just going to bypass it. I'll rewrite the one app so there's no chance of any overlap.

Comment: Why do you have a filter criteria on message type when you have bound the Orchestration to the port?  What you have done by adding that Filter both messages bound to the Port and also any other messages published with that message type will also go to that port.  If the other applications orchestrations are bound to the port, then remove the filter and things will work.  Otherwise you are going to have to update the Filter so that it excludes those message that should be going to the new port.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you describe, you wouldn't need to create a new Send Port.

Simply change the URI of the existing Send Port to point to the new database.

Comment: The old port is still required for other BizTalk applications